# How do I fix this comment SQL/PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a simple comment section for a website I'm working on, but there seems to be something awry with my code. Here's the form:

```
    <?php  

 if($_SESSION['authenticated'])  { //// if not logged show registration form 
     echo "<form name='comment' action='addcomment.php' method='get'>";
     echo "<textarea name='CommentText'></textarea>";
     echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />"; 
     echo "</form><br><br>";}
     else {
echo "Please log in to post.";
         }

         $res=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM comments");
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

         while ($row) {
             echo '<p>from</p>';
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
         }


                   ?>
```

And here's the PHP/SQL to add the form data to my database table (the table's named comments)

```
<?php $dbHost = 'cust-mysql-123-17';
        $dbUser = 'user';
        $dbPass = 'mypass';
    $dbName = 'ollie';
$db = mysqli_connect( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName ) or die("Cannot connect"); 


$CommentText = $_GET['CommentText'];        
$email = $_SESSION['authenticated'];

$res=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO 'comments' (email, CommentText) VALUES('$email','$CommentText')");


if ($res){echo"<script lang='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Post successful');
        window.location = 'forum.php';
</script>";}
else{
echo "alert('Post Failed');";
}
?>
```

Whenever I try to run it it shows the "post failed" alert I set up in the last if statement. Help?

Comment: Tables don't use quotes.

Comment: you have sql syntax errors, and are wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). If you had `die(mysqli_error($db))` instead of your "post failed" message, you'd have gotten the exact error message from mysql.

Comment: `<script lang='javascript'`? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_GET` and `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Comment: @Westfield, Not sure if that was a *real* user/pass. But i think its wiser to not put it in example code. I took the liberty to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove quotes from the tablename - if you want to enclose it, use backticks ` (key below escape)

```
$res = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO comments (email, CommentText) VALUES('$email','$CommentText')");
```

about security, i recommend you to learn about `mysqli::real_espace_string` on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Per comments above, should be looking at how not to leave the page open to SQL injection.

Comment: @JaazCole It has a syntax error caused by quotes, he is not asking about security in query, it is good to protect against this but it is not the issue.